# How to check JSON field is empty and null

Tags: java, jackson, lombok

I'm trying to check JSON field empty or null, it is working for the empty string and not working for null

Lombok I just used to override ToString, but I'm using Jackson library

```
import lombok.ToString;

@ToString
public class DefaultModel {

    private String name;
    private String age;  

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getAge() {
        return age;
    }

    public void setAge(String age) {
        if (age.trim().isEmpty()||age==null) {
            this.age="101";
        } else {
            this.age=age;
        }
    }
}
```

This is controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/default", method=RequestMethod.POST)
public DefaultModel m1(@RequestBody() DefaultModel model) {
    System.out.println(model);
    return model;
}
```

It's working for empty string but not when i haven't pass JSON field in body

Failure case:

```
{
    "name":"some"
}
```

I know another case is stupidity but I tried, and also I don't even want to give .1% for this null values

```
{
    "name":"some",
    "age":null
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A nice Jackson way to manage the values to be inserted into your deserialized pojo would be implementing a custom Jackson deserializer. In your case it will look something like this:

```
class DefaultModelDeserializer extends JsonDeserializer<DefaultModel> {

    @Override
    public DefaultModel deserialize(JsonParser jp, DeserializationContext ctxt) throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
        DefaultModel responseModel = jp.readValueAs(DefaultModel.class);

        DefaultModel finalModel = new DefaultModel();
        finalModel.setName(responseModel.name);
        finalModel.setAge(responseModel.age == null || age.trim().isEmpty() ? "101" : responseModel.age);

        return finalModel;
    }

}
```

Then your DefaultModel class should be annotated with your custom deserializer:

```
@JsonDeserialize(using = DefaultModelDeserializer.class)
public class DefaultModel {

    ...
}
```

Comment: it's not working if don't pass the property in body, but thanks at least working when i pass `"age":null`

Comment: @Deadpool I didn't understand your question before. I've edited the answer with something I think it will solve your problem.

Comment: i know this one setting default value will solve, but i do have 10 properties like this and not recommended to set default value

Comment: is there any way to check missing JSON fields ? so that we can do something in setter method to resolve it or any annotations etc..

Comment: @Deadpool yes there is. Using a custom Jackson deserializer . I've edited the answer to show what you would need to do.

Answer (score 0):

in your if-statement: `if (age.trim().isEmpty() || age==null)` the null-check needs to come first, otherwise you will get a NullPointerException when the `age.trim()` method is called if the value is null.

E.g. just change it to: `if (age==null || age.trim().isEmpty())`

Comment: it will not work in one case, when we don't send that field in body

Comment: @Deadpool You keep thinking about JSON, but this is an unrelated bug in your code. No matter how `age` comes in, the condition `age.trim().isEmpty() || age==null` is wrong. Unconditionally wrong. Fix such things first, without ever thinking (sometime throwing is the wanted action, but that's a different case and to be written differently). Switch on the warnings, my Eclipse would say something like "condition is always false".